# In Pine Script - How do I work out average volume if less than 3 months available?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have created a table to show the average daily volume over the last 3 months (63 days). Of course for a new IPO, a stock will have less than 63 trading days so far - in this case the table shows "NaN"

Is there a way to show the average volume for last 3 months if available, and if not then average over bars that ARE available?

I tried using an IF statement, but wasn't sure how to define the number of bars. Current code:

```
// Average daily volume - over last 3 months (63 trading days)
AvgVol = ta.ema(volume, 63)
```

```
table.cell(infoDisplay, 0, 3, 'Vol ' + str.tostring(AvgVol, format.volume), bgcolor = AvgVolCondition, text_size = size.small)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if bar_index > 63
    AvgVolume = ta.ema(volume, 63)
```

Let me know if this works for you

Update:

```
ema = ta.ema(volume, 63)
AvgVolume = bar_index > 63? ema : na
```

Comment: Sadly not:
Warning at 49:17 The function 'ta.ema' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope
21:26:00 Error at 51:22 Undeclared identifier 'AvgVol'